# Would the logic of an image slider be a jQuery "pattern"?

Tags: jquery, design-patterns

I want to make something similar to an image slider.  The same logic that goes into a slider is something I need a lot. I know a million plugins and tutorials exist but what I want is to learn from basic jQuery patterns like the 'slider' or 'accordion' without any of the fluff. I want to look over very basic jQuery patterns to learn from.

Would one of the patterns found in the [JavaScript Pattern Collection](http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/) be what I am looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Still a bit over my head at this time. I've run into some of these links and had a few problems understanding how to integrate them into what I was trying to do. I guess I will continue plugging away at http://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough logic in an image slider to warrant a proper software design pattern.

Having a look at your link, many of these are not patterns but simply descriptions of things you can do in javascript

For the image slider itself let's look at it in two components:

User interaction component: buttons (prev, next) or slider

Image component: display image currently selected

All you really have to do is store the index of the currently selected image and lookup what x position to slide the image slider to when you select that image.

Here is a rough example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/bNnEw/

You'll see that it's mostly a functional loop in the beginning that's doing all the leg work and storing the correct indexes to slide the `#images` div to using the animate function in jQuery. This is called when the user interacts with the buttons but just as easily could be called when a slider fires it's slide event. See here for more info on sliders: http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Personally I would take all this functional programming and put it into a proper javascript module. Check out this link for a great example of how to use the module pattern: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Basically the concept of an image slider alone does not warrant a pattern, but the utility of wrapping it up in a module so that it is reusable, perhaps even several times on the same page, is definitely worth doing.

Javascript is a functional language and there are a lot of "patterns" for writing clean, portable, functional code but they don't equate to OOP design patterns IMHO.

Enjoy the fiddle, hope this helps you in your javascripting adventures.

Comment: Noticed that you're trying to pack up general slider functionality... oh well, free image slider :D

Comment: Definitely check out my link about javascript module patterns, that will be super useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

i wouldn't be calling slider functionality a pattern , it is more of a trick ..
patterns for jQuery are really limited (compared to js it self .. or other languages although jQuery is not to be considered a language as it is a derivative work of js)

now patterns for jQuery (or in most cases all of the patterns) are just a way of code organization , and code-tricks ..

jQuery patterns exist for plugin authoring ... you can take a look at [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/) , or read the code with extensive commenting on [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com) ..

back to your question , no there is no pattern for you to use that is related to the core function , but you can use one to organize and have a better extensible code at future .